# Is there a quick way to check if a web page/resource needs login credentials?

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file

I need to write a script that checks a large number of web resources to see if they require HTTP authentication to view.

Is there a quick way to do this, either with a batch file or a shell script. (or powershell). I've tried a few different scripts but always get a http 200 Status code (successful)

I need to output to be something like this:

```
Url                            http code   credentials needed?
www.mywebsite.com/en/page.jsp  200         yes
```

a 401 code would  work as well, as long as I know it asks for credentials.

Here is a small powershell script I used but that doesn't work as I thought it would. (requests seem to time out most of the time):

```
## The URI list to test 
$URLListFile = "C:\URLList1.txt"  
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$Result = @() 

 "<HTML><TITLE>Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B>     </TD</TR>" |Out-File -append C:\Scripts\Test.htm 

Foreach($Uri in $URLList) { 

Write-Host $Uri

$request = $null 
$request = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Uri)
$request.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
$request.PreAuthenticate = $true
$request.timeout = 2000

$time = try{ 
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    $request = $_.Exception.Response 
    $time = -1 
}   

$result = [PSCustomObject] @{ 
    Time = Get-Date; 
    Uri = $uri; 
    StatusCode = [int] $response.StatusCode; 
    StatusDescription = $response.StatusDescription; 
    ResponseLength = $response.RawContentLength; 
    auth = $response.IsMutuallyAuthenticated;
    TimeTaken =  $time; 
}  

foreach($Entry in $result){ 
    if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200") 
    { 
        "<TR bgcolor=red>" |Out-File -append C:\Scripts\Test.htm 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        "<TR>" |Out-File -append C:\Scripts\Test.htm 
    } 
    "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.auth)</TD></TR>" |Out-File -append   C:\Scripts\Test.htm 
}
$request=$null;
$response=$null;

} 
"<HTML><TITLE>Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-  color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B></TD</TR>" |Out-File -append C:\Scripts\Test.htm 
"</Table></BODY></HTML>" |Out-File -append C:\Scripts\Test.htm 
Invoke-Expression C:\Scripts\Test.htm
```

Comment: No, there is no general way to tell whether a page requires login. This is because it's often a human judgement based on your intent (people who want to post would say StackOverflow requires login. People who just want to browse would say it doesn't.)

Comment: It's a basic apache auth login, would that change anything? I am given a 401 when I cancel the login dialog box.

Comment: Yes, that makes a huge difference (I updated the wording). Sadly, I don't know powershell, but if anyone finds your question while looking for a Unix shell equivalent, it would be `[ "$(curl --silent -w "%{http_code}" http://example.com/ -o /dev/null)" = "401" ]`).

Comment: Thanks! I have access to linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

The exception raised by an authentication failure contains a nested exception with the server response:

```
try { 
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
} catch {
    $statusCode = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response.StatusCode.value__
    if ($statusCode -eq 401) { 'Authentication required.' }
}
```

Note that this only works for HTTP authentication. I don't think there's a reliable method for determining if a website requires authentication on the application level.